# Inserting if else in a mathematical expression is it possible

Tags: functions, notation

Hope you guys can help me out. I have a mathematical expression which I constructed its:
$$
A_S = \frac{A_{U_{Max}} - A_{U_{Min}}}{U\sqrt{2}}
$$

Is there a way in which I could mathematically specify along with this equation that if
$A_{U_{Max}}=A_{U_{Min}}=$NULL then $A_S = U$? This would then mean that the variable $A_S$ could basically have two values it could either be equal to $U$ on the condition that $A_{U_{Max}}$=NULL and $A_{U_{Min}}$=NULL or it could be something else depending on the values of $A_{U_{Max}}$ and $A_{U_{Min}}$.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I meant if Aumax and Aumin do not exist . If they do not exist then they are null

Comment: Yes, it is usually used for continuous Probability ditstribution functions

Comment: What is "do not exist"? Like a) in statistics: that data were not explored/missing data? Or shall "does not exist" mean mathematically b): is infinite/singular? Or, c), since "min"/"max" is involved: the "min"/"max" do not exist as denotable numbers in a set/range, and we have to use "sup"/"inf" instead?

Comment: Like a) in statistics: that data were not explored/missing data. Here its going to be missing data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common notation is

$$A_s = \begin{cases}
\ U & \text{if $A_{U_{Max}} = A_{U_{Min}} =$ Null},\\
\ \frac{A_{U_{Max}} - A_{U_{Min}}}{U\sqrt{2}} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what i needed. By the way how do i insert mathematical expressions here

Comment: You can use LaTex. It is a common tool to write mathematics and many tutorials are online.

Comment: @Rajeshwar Information on entering mathematical expressions can be found in this supplemental faq: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117

Comment: @PZZ is it also possible to specify with the above expression on the line {if $A_{U_{Max}} = A_{U_{Min}} =$ Null} something like  and trigger = true to show that if these values are null then trigger is true otherwise its false ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar, perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) can be useful to you

Comment: @Rajeshwar I'm not sure if there is a common notation for this, although I'm sure you could tinker with the Iverson bracket to get this. However, for the sake of clarity, I would specify this fact in english before or after presenting the equation in whatever text you are writing.